# How to customize the last row of a CellTable in GWT?

Tags: gwt, celltable

Assume each row has the format:

```
Data   | <Delete Button>
```

Now I am trying to add an empty row at the end. And I would like to not showing the `<Delete Button>` at the last row. I added the empty data through data provider. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method you can override when you create a column:

```
Column<MyObject, Number> myColumn = new Column<MyObject, Number>(new NumberCell()) {

    @Override
    public String getCellStyleNames(Context context, MyObject myObject) {
        return context.getIndex() == displayItems.size() - 1 ? "hide" : null;
    }  
};
```

`context.getIndex()` gives you a row number. You can define a CSS style in your CSS file like "hide" with a rule "opacity: 0" or "display: none", and return this style only for the last row.

My example is NumberCell, but it applies to all cells.